# Loading image php/html

Tags: php, html

all
i've got some button image on my website
here is the code:

```
  echo "<div class=\"contenitoreeventi\">
   <form method='get' action='paginaevento.php'>
      <input type='submit' 
      style='background-image: url(../fotoluoghi/$foto[$i].png);' 
      class='fotoevento' 
      name='idfesta' 
      value='$idfesta[$i]'/>
       </form>
       ";
```

i want to know if it's possible show a circular progress bar while the image is loaded, can you help me, please?

**EDIT**

This is what i tried

```
echo "<div class=\"contenitoreeventi\ style='background-image: url(IMG/circularloading.gif);'>
       <form method='get' action='paginaevento.php'>
          <input type='submit' 
          style='background-image: url(../fotoluoghi/$foto[$i].png);' 
          class='fotoevento' 
          name='idfesta' 
          value='$idfesta[$i]'/>
           </form>
           ";
```

it doesn't work

Comment: Why you are generating DOM with php? You can use js for do this. If you use javascript, you can easily do what you want(showing progress bar)

Comment: Why use php or js, why not just plain 'O html?

Comment: usually to do this, the webs take a "estimated time" pe: if a picture of 100kb spend 0.5 seconds, do the calculations to more pictures/kb. if someone knows the real solution to your problem, I am interested too.

Comment: the simpliest way is to put your input tag in a DIV and to set background img for that div - the `circularProgressingBar.gif` so while input background is not there - you can see the div background, but once input background is there it just overlap that div background

Comment: I dont see your question here. you say 'progress bar while the image is loaded' what image? the background image? thats must be a big image if the loading of it takes enough time to require a progress bar. fyi you have no closing 'div'

Comment: without Javascript, you need to break your event in this way: submit -> releoad the same page with a div and an image of loading visible (paste and quote or simply parametrize the visibility of this div with image) -> at the end of operations another redirect to the same page in original state. But javascript works much better.

Answer (score 0):

Use input type image with onload atribute.

```
<input type="image" onload="hideProgressCircle();">
```

Create js function to hide progress circle hideProgressCircle() and show it as soon as you can.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp